# file path in QT pri file via function

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake, qt6

I am creating a function in a .pri file that will be included in a .pro file with the intent of being able to do:

```
template(subdirs)
addMyProject(libA)
addMyProject(libB)
addMyProject(libC)
```

instead of

```
template(subdirs)
SUBDIRS += libA
libA.path = source/
SUBDIRS += libB
libB.path = source/
SUBDIRS += libC
libC.path = source/
```

Same problem if I want to use the depend keyword.

My current implementation is the following one:

```
defineTest(addMyProject) {

  library_name = $$1

  SUBDIRS += $$library_name
  export(SUBDIRS)

  {$$library_name}.file = {$$library_name}/source/{$$library_name}.pro
  QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += {$$library_name}
  export(QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS)
}
```

The SUBDIRS part is ok. I have tried to make it work for the .file part in different ways, but still I have not found a solution.

Any hints?

[EDIT]

Each library contains different sub-projects, and the goal is to let Qt creator see only one of them (the one at the path source/libraryname.pro).
The issue is that all the libraries are correctly displayed, but also all the other sub-projects. Basically, only the SUBDIRS variable is recognised, but not the .file keyword)

Comment: You haven't described very well the part that's not working. Are you getting an error?

Comment: I'll edit the question. Thank you for the hint

Comment: Are you trying to include multiple .pro files from the same directory?

Comment: Each project and each sub-project reside in a different directory.  headers, cpp and the real .pro file (not the SUBDIRS one) reside all within the source directory